# Cluster Labels Storage in Carrot2

Tags: carrot2

Where the cluster labels are stored in Carrot2? After storing the labels, the `FoamTree` and `Circle` results are generated, but where are these labels stored? How can I get them using some code etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Carrot2 is stateless, it does not store the labels anywhere. It simply generates clusters in response to the documents you feed in.

The simplest way to integrate Carrot2 with FoamTree, Circles or any other JavaScript visualization is to up [Carrot2 Document Clustering Server (DCS)](http://project.carrot2.org/download-dcs.html), make requests to the DCS directly from your browser using Ajax and once the clusters are received, [show the clusters in the visualization](http://get.carrotsearch.com/foamtree/latest/api/#carrot2-models).